# "I'm sorry to hear that" vs "I'm sorry for that" as a response

Tags: phrase-usage

My friend called me and told he that he failed in an exam.

In my language, we usually say:

> I'm sorry **to hear that**.

while in English, I've noticed people mostly using:

> I'm sorry **for that**.

My question is—

#### Is "I'm sorry to hear that" correct as a response in English as in my language?

Comment: Also informally "Sorry 'bout that." (AmE)

Answer (score 7):

**Yes, it's idiomatic to use *sorry to hear that* in this sort of context**. In fact, [you could argue that it's more prevalent than saying *sorry for that*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sorry%20to%20hear%20that%2Csorry%20for%20that%2Csorry%20about%20that&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csorry%20to%20hear%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csorry%20for%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csorry%20about%20that%3B%2Cc0). Another common phrase is *sorry about that*.

You could also make the case that saying *sorry for that* indicates that you might be accepting some of the blame for the bad consequences, whereas saying *sorry to hear that* would only ever indicate that you are consoling someone.

Comment: Thank you 1+. What about "I'm sorry **to know** that"?

Comment: @VersatileandAffordable, that would have a different meaning.  With bad news, there is unpleasantness associated with the news, but knowing the news is necessary to react or console.  "Sorry to know that" would go to not wanting to know, like burying your head in the sand.

Comment: Kindly, can you give me an example for usage in this phrase?

Answer (score 1):

People commonly say "sorry to hear that" in this context.

You wouldn't normally say "I'm sorry for that" unless it was something you did. Like, "Hey, somebody broke my chair." "Oh, yeah, I broke it last night. I'm sorry for that."

Comment: Thank you1+ What do you think about: "I'm sorry **about** that"? is also -for your opinion- just for things that I do? By the way, which English do you represent? (Br, Am, Aus, Ca?)

Comment: "I'm sorry about that" could be used in either case, as an apology or to express sympathy. As an apology it's generally considered a weak apology, the sort of thing you say if you're not REALLY sorry or don't see it as a big issue. Like, "You stepped on my foot!" "Oh, sorry about that." If someone said, "Your mistake cost me $10,000" and you replied, "Oh, sorry about that", they would not be satisfied.

Comment: I'm an American. When we get into regional variations, I grew up in New York but have spent most of my life in the Great Lakes area.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and comments. I've learnt from you things that I didn't know before. I appreciate it.